# Hive- Delete duplicate rows using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: hive

How to delete duplicates using row_number() without listing all the columns from the table. I have a hive table with 50+ columns. If i want to delete duplicates based on a 2 columns below are the steps i followed

- Create temp table as `Create temptable as select * from (select
  *,row_number() over(col1,col2) as rn from maintable) where rn=1)`
- `Insert overwrite table maintable select * from temptable`

But here in insert it fails because the new column `rn` is present in temptable; To avoid this column i would have to list all the rest of the columns.

And there is no Drop column option in hive. There also you need to use REPLACE function which again needs listing all the rest of the columns.

So any better idea for deleting duplicates in Hive based on 2 columns?

Comment: If you already have Main table with all the columns (50+), then try <show create table tableName> which will list out all columns, then use this column list in select clause of insert overwrite

Answer (score 1):

Spell out all column names from the original table for `insert overwrite` as the query computes a new column. No temp table is needed for this.

```
Insert overwrite table maintable 
select col1,col2,col3 ---...col50 
from (select t.*
            ,row_number() over(order by col1,col2) as rn 
      from maintable
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Yup. even if it reduces temp table. My concern was with listing all the columns. Seems there is no other option